# How can you disable the `vscode://` URI security prompt in VSCode?

Tags: security, configuration, visual-studio-code, custom-url-protocol

I'm developing in PHP and using Xdebug which i configured to turn file paths into `vscode://file:/`-links.

Until recently VSCode would simply open the file and jump to the specified line, but now it seems they have added an additional prompt in VSCode (as seen below) as a security measure.

The prompt reads: "An external application wants to open 'C:\path\file.php' in Code. Do you want to open this file or folder?'

I've searched the internet and the settings and settings.json for any option. **How can i disable this prompt?**

[VSCode screenshot of the security prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGhL7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can disable the confirmation prompt as of this writing.  You can follow the [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95670) for updates.